# material distributed based on mesh and not on vertex

Tags: materials, node-editor, scale

My Question is about materials. I want to create a T-Shirt, who has this pattern on like show in the Picture. My Problem is, that want to have the "Image Texture" based on the mesh, and not based on the density of the vertex. So that the Pattern is evenly distributed.
[image]
Here the pattern is evenly distributed
[image]
Here it isn't
(In the two pictures I showed you two times the Note Editor. I did this because you only need the first three Nodes, but I thought, perhaps do you need all.
edit 1:
[image]
Here you see the unequal spreading of the pattern over the T-Shirt
(After UV-Mapping(@Bruno)
edit 2:
[image]
I finally approche to the result that i want to have. I have to us smart uv protection. But as you can see in the image, it has a few places, with not perfect patterns, as under the armpit. How can i fix them?

Comment: By design, UV maps are based on the position of vertices thus the texture will stretch if you stretch the vertices away from each other. What model/mesh are you targetting?

Comment: I target a T-Shirt as I said. Or what do you mean?

Comment: OK so have you tried UV unwrapping your TShirt on the texture?

Comment: i showed my problem in the Answer as edit 1 and 2

Answer (score 2):

I finally fixed the last problems
[image]
With the help of removing vertex form the shrinkwrap modifier, i made it for my goal, perfekt. Smart uv protektion was the key. Thanks Bruno.

Comment: What do you mean "removing vertex form the shrinkwrap modifier"?

Comment: i made a new vertex group and asinge only the vertexes i want to have the shrinkwrap modifier on it

Comment: got it thank you